# Extraction of complete rows from CSV using list , we dont know row indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Can somebody help me in solving the below problem

I have a CSV, which is relatively large with over 1 million rows X 4000 columns. Case ID is one of the first column header in csv. Now I need to extract the complete rows belonging to the few case Ids, which are documented in  list as faulty IDs.

****Note: I dont know the indices of the required case IDs****

Example >  the CSV is - production_data.csv and the faulty IDs, faulty_Id= [ 50055, 72525, 82998, 1555558]

Now, we need to extract the complete rows for faulty_Id= [ 50055, 72525, 82998, 1555558]

Best Regards

Comment: What about reading the rows one at a time and only keeping the ones with relevant values in the Case ID column? What have you tried so far?

Comment: By "*extract the complete rows"* do you mean that you want to create a new "good" CSV with about 1 million good rows but with out those few bad rows, or do you mean you want a new "bad" CSV with just the bad rows in it and leaving the original one un-altered?

Answer (score 0):

If your faculty_id is present as header in csv file, you can use pandas dataframe to [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and set index as faculty_id and extract rows based on the faculty_id. For more info attach sample data of csv

Answer (score 0):

*CSV, which is relatively large with over 1 million rows X 4000 columns*

As CSV are just text files and it is probably to big to be feasible to load it as whole I suggest using [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) built-in module, if ID is 1st column, then create `extractfaults.py` as follows:

```
import fileinput
faulty = ["50055", "72525", "82998", "1555558"]
for line in fileinput.input():
    if fileinput.lineno() == 0:
        print(line, end='')
    elif line.split(",", 1)[0] in faulty:
        print(line, end='')
```

and use it following way

```
python extractfaults.py data.csv > faultdata.csv
```

Explanation: keep lines which are either 1st line (header) or have one of provided ID (I used optional 2nd `.split` argument to limit number of splits to 1). Note usage of `end=''` as `fileinput` keeps original newlines. My solution assumes that IDs are not quoted and ID is first column, if any of these does not hold true, feel free to adjust my code to your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you is to use a database like Postgres or MySQL. You can copy your data to the database first and then easily operate rows and columns. The file in your case is not the best solution since you need to upload all the data from the file to the memory to be able to process it. And file opening takes a lot of time in addition.